# Azure functions CosmosDB Trigger using User assigned managed identity

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-changefeed

I'm trying to use "User assigned managed identity" among all my Azure functions and consume change feed. The cosmosDB trigger function is not using the identity. I provided connectionPrefix__clientId in the app settings as well. Does the trigger support User assigned managed identity ?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta The MSI approach is working well with System managed identity. But it is not working with User assigned. I see the only difference between both identities is adding "prefix__clientId" for user identity. Just wondering if cosmosDB trigger specifically supports user identity ?

Comment: Yes it does. The Type of the Identity is transparent to the Triggers (any trigger). For other type of identities, you need other attributes besides clientId, you might need tenantId and secret: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference?tabs=cosmos#local-development-with-identity-based-connections. This is general for all Azure Function Triggers, not Cosmos DB specific.